# Order dates from a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I read multiple dates from a file and I put every date in a vector of struct like this:

```
struct value {
    string code;
    string date;
    string name;
};
```

(the format of the date is “`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`")

Now I want to order the dates of the vector.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you mean sorting the dates within `std::vector`?

Comment: Order by which concrete criteria actually?

Comment: in chronological order..

Comment: @Fr4ncx Which vector actually? What did you try, where are you stuck upon?

Comment: i have a vector of struct ( vector<value>)

Comment: Unless you convert to an actual date/datetime, or some numeric part, you will be sorting alphabetically. This may not have much of a difference if you are assured the format above and all single digits are padding with a leading zero. It is just worth noting that an alpha sort is not the same as numeric sort.

Comment: @Fr4ncx Improve your question please.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have to order a  vector  which contains dates in descending order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **[`std::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)** algorithm on your `vector`:

```
vector<value> v; 
...
std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), [](value&a, value&b)->bool { return a.date<b.date; });
```

**Fortunately**, the date format you are using is so that the alphabetical order corresponds to the chronological order.  If this would not be the case, you'd have to add a date conversion.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/3OJRX7)

Comment: error: C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'lettura' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: std::sort (v.begin(), v.end(), [](value&a, value&b) { return a.date<b.date; });

Comment: @GeorgeHoupis yes of course ! In the hurry I forgot the .date !

Comment: @Christophe I figured :)   Although, he could also have the operator < defined, then the lambda would be unnecessary.